# Dividing the array in K parts

Tags: arrays, algorithm

let the array

```
 A[0] = 2
  A[1] = 1
  A[2] = 5
  A[3] = 1
  A[4] = 2
  A[5] = 2
  A[6] = 2
```

I have to divide the array in K parts such that larger sum is low.

 For example k=3

```
[2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 2, 2], [], [] with a large sum of 15;
[2], [1, 5, 1, 2], [2, 2] with a large sum of 9;
[2, 1, 5], [], [1, 2, 2, 2] with a large sum of 8;
[2, 1], [5, 1], [2, 2, 2] with a large sum of 6.
```

So the algorithm should return 6.

 Which algorithm should i use , is this a modified version of KMP algorithm.
Please provide me a approach

Comment: What kind of elements are there in the array? If only positive numbers, it greatly simplifies the problem. If only positive limited-range integers (like 32-bit unsigned ints), it simplifies the problem even more.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev only postive number are there

Comment: For this case David's answer is probably the best you can get.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you can use dynamic programming for this. Think of it this way - if you make a cut and put the first m elements into the first chunk, then the resulting maximum value will be the minimum value of the sum of the first m elements and the minimum value you can get by cutting the last n - m elements into k - 1 pieces. As a base case, if you run out of elements, the minimum value is ∞.

More formally, let S[n, k] be the minimum maximum value you can make using the first n elements of the array if you have to make k cuts. You can write out this recurrence:

> S[0, k] = ∞ for any k (if you have no elements in the array and have to make any number of cuts, the value is infinite).
>
> S[n, k] = min<sub>m ≤ n</sub>{ max(A[n] + A[n - 1] + ... + A[n - m], S[n - m, k - 1] } for n > 0 (you peel off some number of elements from the back, computing the min as the best choice you can make.

You'll need to fill in a table of Θ(nk) total elements, and filling in the element at position (n', k') will take time Θ(n'). Therefore, the total runtime will be Θ(n<sup>2</sup>k).

As a heuristic, you may be able to speed this up a bit. In particular, as soon as A[n] + A[n - 1] + ... + A[m] becomes bigger than S[n - m, k - 1], you know that you've peeled off too many elements into the group in front and therefore can stop evaluating larger values of m. This is just a heuristic, but it may give you some performance benefits in practice.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @user4018473 Can you elaborate?

Comment: time complexity of this algorithm is high so that's why

Comment: @user4018473 Can you give more description about the problem you're facing? Is this for a programming contest, for homework, for fun? How big are the inputs going to be? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have used divide and conquer(similar to Maximum Subarray Sum) and it is just for improving my algorithms skills

Answer (score 1):

There's an `O(kn)`-time optimization of templatetypedef's DP that works as follows. Let `P(i, j)` be the greatest optimal position of the last boundary between subarrays when dividing the first `j` elements into `i` parts. Then `P(i, j)` is nondecreasing in `i`. We exploit this fact as follows (lightly tested Python).

```
def minmaxsum(A, k):
    S = [0]  # partial sums
    for x in A:
        S.append(S[-1] + x)
    n = len(A)
    # V0 is the optimal objective values for the (i, j) subproblems
    V0 = [1e309] * (n + 1)  # 1e309 is infinity
    V0[0] = 0
    for j in range(k):
        # V1 is the optimal objective values for the (i + 1, j) subproblems
        V1 = []
        i0 = 0
        for i1 in range(n + 1):
            # the while loop is amortized constant-time
            while i0 < n and \
                    max(V0[i0], S[i1] - S[i0]) >= \
                        max(V0[i0 + 1], S[i1] - S[i0 + 1]):
                i0 += 1
            V1.append(max(V0[i0], S[i1] - S[i0]))
        V0 = V1
    return V0[n]
```

To improve this solution further, likely close to linear-time on sufficiently "unlumpy" inputs, we observe that `sum(A) / k` is a lower bound on the cost of any solution. Thus, for a split at `i`, we have the lower bound `max(sum(A[:i]) / (k - 1), sum(A[i:]))`. Using this bound, we may be able to use binary search to find the likeliest split points and then evaluate only a handful of the DP entries, using the bound to rule out the rest.